# change fragment layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have two tabs, which are fragments, and one is for login (login fragment). After it clicks login, a new activity (login activity) will pop up, and then the user needs to login. If he has successfully logged in, the login activity will be closed by using `finish()`. And then I want to change the layout of the tab from login fragment to welcome fragment, using `onActivityResult()`.

I have two layouts created, login fragment layout and welcome fragment layout. However, I do not know how to change the layout since `setContentView()` cannot be used.

```
public class UserLoginTab extends Fragment {

String username = "";

Button loginButton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_login_tab, container, false);

    loginButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            username=data.getStringExtra("username");
            //change layout here and add the username to a textView
            //The layout is (R.layout.welcome_tab)
        }
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two XML layout files: `login.xml` and `welcome.xml`. For each XML layout file, you should create a class which extends `Fragment`: `LoginFragment` and `WelcomeFragment`. Then in the `FragmentPagerAdapter` subclass, write some logic which decides which of these two fragments to display. You could have some kind of `loggedIn` flag, possibly stored in `SharedPreferences` which indicates whether or not the user is already logged in.

Comment: I am using `FragmentPagerAdapter` to maintain them. It will create the fragment class object when it is on that tab

Comment: @androidnewbie See my edited answer for more details.